# Por que se usa um vetor com nome dentro?

Tags: c, c++

gostaria de saber qual a função de se usar um nome dentro de um vetor?

```
char chave[NUM_LETRAS + 1]; 
int frequencias[NUM_LETRAS];
int frequencias2[NUM_LETRAS];
char codificado[MAX_STR];
char descrip[MAX_STR];
```

Comment: normalmente esse "nome" é uma variável que possui um valor, por exemplo, no começo do código deve haver MAX_STR = 255;

Comment: e tem que ser sempre maiúsculo os nomes? pois tentei alterar e não deu

Comment: tem que se o mesmo que foi declarado, ou seja, **int max_str = 255;** deve se usar minusculo

Comment: fgets(codificado, MAX_STR, stdin); e essa função?

Answer (score 4):

Geralmente nomes em maiúsculo denotam valores constantes, valores que não irão mudar no decorrer do programa, mas nada impede desses valores terem nome em minúsculo também. É apenas uma questão de boa prática. Um breve exemplo de uso:

```
#define NUM_LETRAS 50
#define num_letras 25
#define MAX_STR 255

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* Aqui, o compilador troca NUM_LETRAS pelo valor definido acima,
     * criando um vetor de caracteres de 51 letras (50 + 1)
     */
    char chave[NUM_LETRAS + 1];

    /* Já aqui, o compilador troca num_letras por 25,
     * criando um vetor de caracteres de 26 letras (25 + 1)
     */
    char chave2[num_letras + 1];

    // O mesmo ocorre aqui
    char codificado[MAX_LEN];

    /* fgets() lê de uma fonte de entrada de dados 
     * (no caso 'stdin') o número MAX_STR (255) de letras
     * e coloca dentro do vetor 'codificado'.
     */
    fgets(codificado, MAX_STR, stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

Constantes são úteis quando um mesmo número que se refere sempre a mesma coisa durante o código é repetido várias vezes. Isso facilita alterações no código, ao invés de procurar todos os valores 255 do programa que se referem ao tamanho máximo de uma string, ele simplesmente muda o valor definido para MAX_STR.

Por consequência, o código fica mais legível, pois essa solução evita o uso de "números mágicos" (valores numéricos que ninguém sabe de onde veio e a que se refere), substituindo valores explicitos sem descrição por nomes auto-explicativos.

Answer (score 3):

Parece que você confundiu algumas coisas. Em C/C++:

- t foo[*bar*]

Representa a declaração de uma variável ***foo*** de tipo ***t***, alocando um espaço de endereçamento contínuo (vetor), e finalmente atribuindo o endereço da primeira posição deste vetor à variável ***foo***, de tamanho ***bar***. Logo, teremos ***bar*** variáveis do tipo ***t*** alocadas continuamente, e o valor do ponteiro ***foo*** será o endereço de memória da primeira posição deste vetor.

No seu exemplo:

```
char chave[NUM_LETRAS + 1];
```

Significa que temos um vetor, armazenando variáveis do tipo char, de tamanho `NUM_LETRAS + 1`. Neste caso, o nome `NUM_LETRAS` provavelmente representa uma macro de pré-processamento definida via `#define` (`#define NUM_LETRAS 10` por exemplo).

Answer (score 0):

Isso evita a declaração de posições desnecessárias em um vetor, pois o próprio usuário tem a opção de digitar a quantidade de espaços desejados. Um exemplo seria o cadastro de nomes em um vetor:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{
    int tam; // <- variável que armazena o tamanho do vetor.

    cout<<"Digite a quantidade de nomes que deseja inserir: ";
    cin>>tam; // <- usuário digita a quantidade de posições desejada.

    string nomes[tam]; // <- vetor de tamanho definido pelo usuário.


    ... // segue código.
```

Comment: Lembrando que o suporte a VLAs (variable length array) é opcional em C11, e foi removido por completo em C++.